# Executar callback ao fechar teclado android

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic

Tenho um *app* rodando com Cordova e Ionic. Nesse *app* eu gostaria de efetuar uma ação em determinado `controller` quando o teclado se fechar por completo.

Hoje estou utilizando `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();`. Atualmente o teclado fecha normalmente. Porém, acredito que não tenha um *callback* nessa função.

Qual a maneira de quando o teclado se fechar por completo, só depois então executar algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
$scope.reportEvent = function (event) {
  if (event.type == 'doubletap') {
      $timeout(function () {
          if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              if(cordova.plugins.Keyboard.isVisible){
                  window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
              } else {
                  window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
              }

          }
       }, 500);
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Em Android puro, não existe um listener que indique o evento de fechamento do teclado.

O que muitos fazem é implementar um ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681196/7762411) tem um post do SOen explicando.

Em cordova, eu achei que no plugin com.ionic.keyboard, ele tem os seguintes eventos ([link](https://github.com/StephenGrider/CoffeeScript-Ionic-Starter/tree/master/plugins/com.ionic.keyboard)):

> Evento para tratar quando o teclado aparece. Internamente implementa a estratégia acima

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    alert('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);
}
```

> Evento para tratar quando o teclado some

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    alert('Goodnight, sweet prince');
}
```